# React component lifecycle methods and remote api calls

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

The documentation states one should use lifecycle methods componentDid*** to place network calls to fetch remote data.

Suppose I use react-redux and the mapStateToProps function investigates current state of the store and prepare the props instance. This is the point when the algorithm knows for the first time that it needs some data from a remote server. But it does not have reference to dispatch-function and cannot dispatch an action (or thunk to be precise) at this point.

I have to wait until componentDid* lifecycle method and use the result of (mapDispatchToProps) to initiate the remote transaction.

My understanding is that the wrapped component in most cases might not need to know anything about remote api calls.

Will it be legitimate to extract the logic from the wrapped component and place it in MergeProps callback of the connect function producing the HOC? I did not find any reference to such a usage. [image]

Comment: Version A is not so logical since you connect the parent component to store but do the fetch in Child. Version B is more logical and this is when we use container components. Why a HOC? Just create a container, do the fetch there, connect it to store then pass the data to your child component.